# Comparison between the different vehicles in Fortnite—Battle Royale?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

There are now three vehicles in Fortnite. The Shopping Cart, ATK and Quad-Crasher. I would like to compare them in several tasks.

First off, without any boosts on a flat surface, which one is fastest and the slowest?

Now, If I am going downhill, what are the results?

They all have their unique abilities. What are they and what can they accomplish? What is the time delay between using abilities?

Which one has the most Health Points (HP)?

Lastly, what is the spawn rate of each?

Comment: The ATK can honk and the shopping cart cannot

Answer (score 0):

Quadcrasher is a vehicle in Battle Royale. It seats two players and builds up boost just by anyone sitting in the driver's seat. Using the boost will speed up the Quadcrasher and make it able to smash through almost anything. Driving into players while boosting will send them flying upwards, potentially causing major fall damage. The boost can also be used to get some big airtime on ramps or to climb up mountains. Quadcrasher can be found throughout specific locations of the map and spawns all the time. HP 400

ATK (stands for All Terrain Kart) is a vehicle in Battle Royale. It can fit 4 players and gets speed boosts after powersliding. It's roof acts like tires.HP 400

Shopping Carts allow a driver, which can move and push the Shopping Cart, and a passenger, which can shoot, build, harvest materials and use emotes. They cannot crouch, however. Shopping Carts are seemingly hidden around the map, usually in corners, inside buildings, on top of mountains, etc. Just like the majority of objects, their spawn points are variable and therefore, they cannot be always found on the same spot. HP 400

from wiki fortnite

fastest is the quadcrasher, then atk, then shopping cart.
hope this answered your question GamerM